# What kind of hardware is needed to run Skype well?

Tags: hardware, skype

I have been asked to choose a cheap tablet to buy for Skype video calling. The person who will use it isn't going to do anything fancy else, just videocalling her daughter at evening.

I have seen products like Mediacom's SmartPad 706i featuring:

- 512MB of RAM
- 1GHz single-core CPU

I wonder if these are good for smooth calling, considering that no other applications are supposed to run meanwhile.

I'm not asking, as per policy, for a recommendation on which product to buy.  What hardware characteristics are most important for video calling using Skype?

Comment: See this Skype Forum where a person has asked about "Skype on Android Tablets" http://community.skype.com/t5/Android/Skype-on-Android-tablets/td-p/501347

Comment: I have no problem voice calling on my phone with those specs but haven't tried video calling.

Comment: I'd generally say that any tablet that nowaday comes with a front camera suffices to run Skype decently.

Comment: OH: Stick to ARM CPU's, mips and x86 may be [unsupported](http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Developer-Corner/About-Skype-of-Android-for-MIPS/td-p/13104) still. Plus maybe chinese pre-4.0/ICS el-cheapo tablets often have crappy video drivers, so get a recent one. Probably get the cheapest Nexus line tablet (currently the Nexus 7 16GB), it's really good in comparision to the few bucks you can save with a chinese no-name tablet.

Comment: @ce4 anything priced over 150€ is "too expensive" for this person. +1 for ARM. Nexus 7 priced > 250@amazon

Comment: I wouldn't buy the N7 over Amazon, it's available for 199,- in [Google's play store](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details?id=nexus_7_16gb). Plus: The N7 is so much better than any price-competitive tablet, IMHO.